# Method is undefined?

Tags: android, sqlite

When I write the code below, it says that the method `getReadableDatabase()` is undefined for `dbHelper`, what is the problem with it?

```
public void checklogin(String logged){


    DatabaseAdapter dbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(LoginActivity.this);

    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();


    Cursor mCursor = db.query(dbHelper.TABLE_USERS,new String[]{"select * from users"}, " Name like" + "'logged+'",null,null,null,null);

     if  (mCursor.moveToFirst()){
         Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Yaaaay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your implementation of `DatabaseAdapter`?  It's not part of the Android framework.  The only class that I know of that implements `getReadableDatabase()` is [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29).

Comment: Yes I have just realized that. the thing is that I have created the class DatabbaseHelper inside DatabaseAdapter. How can instantiate a variable from the DBhelper in my login.java class? in order to have

dbh = new databaseHelper(this);

Answer (score 0):

It typically means that getReadableDatabase() is not a function in your DatabaseAdapter class.

Comment: Yes I have just realized that. the thing is that I have created the class DatabbaseHelper inside DatabaseAdapter. How can instantiate a variable from the DBhelper in my login.java class? in order to have dbh = new databaseHelper(this); –